# Expected number of coin flips until observing $n$ of the same side

Tags: probability

> **Question**: Consider a coin which is flipped Heads with probability $p$ and Tails with probability $1-p$. Let $C_n$ be the number of tosses until we observe $n$ consecutive Heads or $n$ consecutive Tails (for the first time). Compute $\mathbb{E}[C_n]$.

I am able to determine the expected number of tosses until $n$ consecutive Heads with such a coin. But this relied conditional probability; namely, it involved conditioning upon the number of flips until the first Tail.

For this reason, I can't figure out how to modify my technique when I allow both Heads & Tails to satisfy the $n$-consecutive-flip property.

Also, this was from an old exam, so if there is a way to do this problem with reasonable time-constraints that would be great. Thank you

**EDIT**: Here's work for $H_n$ the number of tosses until we observe $n$ consecutive Heads.

Let $\mu = E[H_n]$ and $F$ denote the first instance of Tails. Then, 
$$
\mu = \sum_{k=1}^\infty E[H_n \mid F=k] P(F=k) = \sum_{k=1}^n (\mu+k) P(F=k) + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty n P(F=k)
$$
where the first term on the RHS indicates that the first Tails was $\le n$, so we "start over" with $\mu$, and the second term indicates that the first $n$ flips were heads. Also note $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty P(F=k)$ is the probability that the first $n$ flips were heads, so this equals $p^n$.

So $\mu \left( 1 - \sum_{k=1}^n P(F=k) \right) = n p^n + \sum_{k=1}^n k P(F=k) \implies \mu = p^n + \frac{1}{p^n} \sum_{k=1}^n k P(F=k).$

Finally, $\sum_{k=1}^n k P(F=k) = \sum_{k=1}^n k (1-p)p^{k-1} = \cdots = \dfrac{-n p^{n + 1} + (n + 1) p^n - 1 }{p - 1}$ after manipulating geometric series. Then, substituting into the formula above gives $\mu = \dfrac{p^{-n}(p^n-1)}{p-1}$.

Comment: its a hitting time in a markov chain

Comment: Look at the 'negative binomial' distribution, which addresses your problem directly. Specifically, [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) seems to be clearly written.

Comment: However, the negative binomial does not relate to CONSECUTIVE tosses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H=1$ iffwe get $n$ consecutive heads before $n$ consecutive tails and $0$ otherwise. We can calculate $A_n=\mathbb{E}[C_n|H=1]$ by conditioning on the flip on which the process of collecting $n$ heads is interrupted by a tail. In other words, if we are interrupted on our first flip, the expected value is now $1+A_n$, if we are interrupted on our second flip, the expected value is now $2+A_n$, if..., if we are interrupted in our $n+1$th flip, the expected value is now $n$. Putting this all together, we get 
$$\begin{align} A_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p^k(1-p)(k+1+A_n)\\ &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p^k(1-p)(k+1)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p^k(1-p)A_n \\ &=\frac{p^{-n}-1}{1-p} \end{align}$$
We can do the same for $B_n=\mathbb{E}[C_n|H=0]$, except that the probabilities will be reversed. Thus we obtain $$B_n=\frac{(1-p)^{-n}-1}{p}$$
To compute $\mathbb{P}(H=1)$ we condition on whether the first flip is a head. Here, we have two possibilities, either the following $n-1$ flips are heads, or one of these $n-1$ flips results in tails, at which point we forget about all previous heads and imagine that our first flip is a tail, thus
$$P=\mathbb{P}(H=1|\text{first flip is heads})=p^{n-1}+(1-p^{n-1})\mathbb{P}(H=1|\text{first flip is tails})$$
To compute $\mathbb{P}(H=1|\text{first flip is tails})$, we have two possibilities again: either the following $n-1$ flips are all tails, in which case the probability of obtaining $n$ consecutive heads before $n$ consecutive tails is zero, or somewhere along the line we get a head, in which case we start all over again as if though our first flip had been a head. Thus
$$Q=\mathbb{P}(H=1|\text{first flip is tails})=(1-(1-p)^{n-1})\mathbb{P}(H=1|\text{first flip is heads})$$
We now have the simultaneous equations
$$\begin{align} P&=p^{n-1}+(1-p^{n-1})Q \\ Q &=(1-(1-p)^{n-1})P\end{align}$$
Which implies that $$P=\frac{p^{n-1}}{1-(1-p^{n-1})(1-(1-p)^{n-1})}$$
$$Q=\frac{p^{n-1}(1-(1-p)^{n-1})}{1-(1-p^{n-1})(1-(1-p)^{n-1})}$$
Remembering we had conditioned on the first flip, we now get
$$\mathbb{P}(H=1)=\frac{p^{n}}{1-(1-p^{n-1})(1-(1-p)^{n-1})}+(1-p)p^{n-1}\frac{1-(1-p)^{n-1}}{1-(1-p^{n-1})(1-(1-p)^{n-1})}$$
Using $$\mathbb{E}[C_n]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[C_n|H]]=A_n\mathbb{P}(H=1)+B_n(1-\mathbb{P}(H=1))$$
We obtain the desired result.

Comment: Sorry not overly familiar with distributions but could one use the geometric distribution for this problem?

Comment: @gowrath I am afraid not, the geometric distribution is used when computing the probability that $n-1$ failures happen before a success, here we need the probability that $n$ successes happen within a given number of trials. However, the geometric distribution can be used to calculate the expected value of the negative binomial.

Comment: It's $n$ consecutive H or $n$ consecutive T, not just $n$ total

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I really need to take a stats class.

Comment: @user365239 I misread that, with first time do you mean that no tails have appeared before?

Comment: No, for example $C_3$ is just the first time HHH or TTT appears

Comment: @user365239 I edited my answer

Comment: I don't think it's correct. How is $P(H=1) = P(n \text{ consecutive heads}) = p$? What you have for $A_n$ and $B_n$ are, respectively, the expected number of tosses for $n$ consecutive heads & $n$ consecutive tails. I need to figure out how to combine them to get the "or" possibility for $C_n$ . . . & I don't think they're independent

Comment: @user365239 I edited my answer again.

Comment: @GuachoPerez Very clever solution, especially with introducing the P and Q probabilities.. Thanks for working through the problem & giving great answer

Comment: @user365239 glad I could help, sorry for all the edits.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we use $z$ for heads and $w$ for tails. We introduce
two generating functions starting with $f_1(z,w):$

$$f_1(z, w) = (1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^{n-1})
\\ \times \left(\sum_{q\ge 0} 
(w+w^2+\cdots+w^{n-1})^q
(z+z^2+\cdots+z^{n-1})^q\right) w^n
\\ = \frac{1-z^n}{1-z}
\\ \times \left(\sum_{q\ge 0}
w^q z^q 
\frac{(1-w^{n-1})^q}{(1-w)^q} \frac{(1-z^{n-1})^q}{(1-z)^q}\right) 
w^n
\\ = w^n \frac{1-z^n}{1-z} 
\frac{1}{1-wz(1-w^{n-1})(1-z^{n-1})/(1-z)/(1-w)}
\\ = w^n (1-w)(1-z^n)
\frac{1}{(1-w)(1-z)-wz(1-w^{n-1})(1-z^{n-1})} 
\\ = w^n (1-w)(1-z^n)
\frac{1}{1-w-z+zw^n+wz^n - w^n z^n}$$

This is the  contribution from configurations ending in  a sequence of
$n$   tails.   We   get   the  generating   function  $f_2(z,w)$   for
configurations ending  in a  sequence of heads  by using  the inherent
symmetry and find

$$f_2(z, w) 
= z^n (1-z)(1-w^n)
\frac{1}{1-w-z+zw^n+wz^n - w^n z^n}.$$

The desired expectation is now given by

$$\left.
\frac{d}{dv}\left(f_1(pv, (1-p)v)+f_2(pv, (1-p)v)\right)
\right|_{v=1}.$$

The sum is

$$\frac{w^n-w^{n+1}-w^nz^n+w^{n+1}z^n
+ z^n-z^{n+1}-w^nz^n+z^{n+1}w^n }
{1-w-z+zw^n+wz^n - w^n z^n}.$$

The substitution yields yields for the denominator

$$D_1 = \left.1-(1-p)v-pv+
p(1-p)^nv^{n+1}+(1-p)p^nv^{n+1}-v^{2n}(1-p)^np^n\right|_{v=1}
\\ = p(1-p)^n + (1-p)p^n - (1-p)^n p^n.$$

We get from the derivative

$$D_2 = -1 +(n+1)p(1-p)^n+(n+1)(1-p)p^n-2n(1-p)^np^n.$$

We get for the numerator

$$N_1 = \left.-2(1-p)^np^n v^{2n} +
(1-p)^n v^n - (1-p)^{n+1} v^{n+1}
+ p^n v^n - p^{n+1} v^{n+1}
\\ + (1-p)^{n+1} p^n v^{2n+1}
+ p^{n+1} (1-p)^n v^{2n+1}\right|_{v=1}
\\ = -2(1-p)^n p^n + p (1-p)^n + (1-p) p^n
+ p^n (1-p)^n
\\ = -(1-p)^n p^n + p (1-p)^n + (1-p) p^n.$$

The derivative produces

$$N_2 = -4n (1-p)^n p^n 
+ n(1-p)^n - (n+1) (1-p)^{n+1} 
+ np^n - (n+1)p^{n+1}
+ (2n+1) (1-p)^{n+1} p^n + (2n+1) p^{n+1} (1-p)^n
\\ = -4n (1-p)^n p^n 
+ n(1-p)^n - (n+1) (1-p)^{n+1} 
+ np^n - (n+1)p^{n+1}
\\ + (2n+1) (1-p)^{n} p^n
\\ = -(2n-1) (1-p)^n p^n 
\\ + n(1-p)^n - (n+1) (1-p)^{n+1} 
+ np^n - (n+1)p^{n+1}.$$

We seek

$$\frac{N_2}{D_1} - \frac{N_1}{D_1^2} D_2
= \frac{N_2}{D_1} - \frac{1}{D_1} D_2
= \frac{N_2-D_2}{D_1}.$$

Now  $$N_2-D_2 =
(1-p)^n p^n - (1-p)^n - p^n + 1.$$

Hence we have the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{(1-p)^n p^n - (1-p)^n - p^n + 1}
{p(1-p)^n + (1-p)p^n - (1-p)^n p^n}.}$$

This is also equal to

$$\frac{(1-p^n)(1-(1-p)^n)}
{p(1-p) - (p-p^n)((1-p)-(1-p)^n)}$$

and hence an alternate closed form is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{p(1-p)} \frac{(1-p^n)(1-(1-p)^n)}
{1 - (1-p^{n-1})(1-(1-p)^{n-1})}.}$$

There is a Perl script  which provides empirical data that approximate
the closed form quite well.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

MAIN: {
    my $n = shift || 3;
    my $p = shift || 0.5;
    my $trials = shift || 1000;

    my $res = 0;

    for(my $tind=0; $tind < $trials; $tind++){
        my ($run, $runlen, $flips) = (-1, 0, 0);

        while($runlen != $n){
            my $HT = ( rand() < $p ? 1 : 0 );

            if($HT == $run){
                $runlen++;
            }
            else{
                $run = $HT;
                $runlen = 1;
            }

            $flips++;
        }

        $res += $flips;
    }

    print $res/$trials;
    print "\n";

    1;
}
```

The Maple code is used to  match the data from the generating function
against data produced by total enumeration and compare the closed form
of the expectation to the symbolics from the generating function.

```
RL :=
proc(n, q)
    option remember;
    local ind, d, pos, cur, run, runs, gf,
    zcnt, wcnt, vcnt;

    gf := 0;

    for ind from 2^q to 2*2^q-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, 2);

        cur := -1; pos := 1;
        run := []; runs := [];


        while pos <= q do
            if d[pos] <> cur then
                if nops(run) > 0 then
                    runs :=
                    [op(runs), [run[1], nops(run)]];
                fi;

                cur := d[pos];
                run := [cur];
            else
                run := [op(run), cur];
            fi;

            pos := pos + 1;
        od;

        runs := [op(runs), [run[1], nops(run)]];

        zcnt := add(`if`(r[1] = 0, r[2], 0), r in runs);
        wcnt := add(`if`(r[1] = 1, r[2], 0), r in runs);

        if(nops(select(r->r[2] >= n, runs)) = 1) and
        runs[nops(runs)][2] = n then
            gf := gf + z^zcnt*w^wcnt;
        fi;
    od;

    gf;
end;

F := (v1, v2, n) ->
v1^n*(1-v1)*(1-v2^n)
/(1-v1-v2+v1*v2^n+v2*v1^n-v1^n*v2^n);

G :=
proc(n, q)
    simplify
    (coeftayl(F(z*v, w*v, n) + F(w*v, z*v, n), v=0, q));
end;

X1 :=
proc(n)

    subs(v=1,
         diff(F(p*v, (1-p)*v, n) + F((1-p)*v, p*v, n), v));
end;

X2 :=
proc(n)
    local CFD, CFN;

    CFN := (1-p)^n*p^n-(1-p)^n-p^n+1;
    CFD := p*(1-p)^n+(1-p)*p^n-(1-p)^n*p^n;

    CFN/CFD;
end;

X3 :=
proc(n)
    local CFD, CFN;

    CFN := (1-p^n)*(1-(1-p)^n);
    CFD := 1-(1-p^(n-1))*(1-(1-p)^(n-1));

    1/p/(1-p)*CFN/CFD;
end;
```